# Can't run the Microphone VAD streaming for Deepspeech

Tags: python, mozilla-deepspeech

I downloaded the model directory for testing out DeepSpeech. As I followed the instructions from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech-examples/blob/r0.6/mic_vad_streaming/README.rst), I got this error:

```
python3 mic_vad_streaming.py --model deepspeech-0.6.1-models/output_graph.pbmm
Initializing model...
INFO:root:ARGS.model: deepspeech-0.6.1-models/output_graph.pbmm
TensorFlow: v1.14.0-21-ge77504a
DeepSpeech: v0.6.0-0-g6d43e21
2020-02-25 15:57:17.741956: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
INFO:root:ARGS.lm: lm.binary
INFO:root:ARGS.trie: trie
[native_client/ctcdecode/scorer.cpp:77] FATAL: "(access(filename, 4)) == (0)" check failed. Invalid language model pathSegmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Can someone help me figure out what's wrong there, please?

Answer (score 1):

I am also facing same problem. just use below command

```
$ export TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL=2
```